# How to determine if onStateChange event was triggered by API or User interaction?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I'm using the Youtube iFrame API for a little app that lets you watch videos in sync with other people. The `onStateChange` event lets me know if a player has played or paused a video, but does it contain any information about whether that action was triggered via the user with a click on the play/pause button, or whether my application triggered a play via the `player.playVideo()` function?

I need to know the difference so I don't get into an infinite loop situation where a player hits pause, that pause event is sent to the other person and I pause the video on their end via `player.pauseVideo()`, which triggers another `onStateChange` pause event, etc etc.

So, does `onStateChange` tell me how the event was triggered, or do I have to come up with a way to keep track of an event's initiator myself?

Comment: I know this is old but did you manage to solve this? I'm in the exactly same pickle, i.e. doing a "watch together" YouTube app. Also, did you finish yours? Perhaps it's open source so I can peek? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[onStateChange](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#onStateChange) only returns an integer data that is related to the state of the player. such as the following:

-1 (unstarted)
0 (ended)
1 (playing)
2 (paused)
3 (buffering)
5 (video cued).

therefore you need to create a custom code that will help identify the source of the event. The implementation can't be as simple as creating a global variable though since you want to sync videos with other people.  You would be needing some server interaction to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I figured. Server side communication is all ready to go just need the right way to interact with the video itself. Might have to look into a different chromeless player or something to do what I want.